# How can I manipulate Dom in React

Tags: reactjs

How can I dynamically create elements in react on click?

what i'm trying to achieve is a form builder something like typeform. The idea is i'll have two fields. the first field will be where i can click a button to select a form input type, maybe a text input area, select box or a radio button, and when i click on that element, react will dynamically create that element for me.

I don't know if anyone understands me, but please i'll appreciate any response. Thanks

Here is what i've done, but i do not this is the right way with react

```
import React, {
Component
 } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';





 class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super()
}





onKeyUp = (e) => {


if (e.keyCode == 13) {


  let div = document.createElement("div");
  document.getElementById("preview").appendChild(div);
  ReactDOM.render(

    <
    div >
    <
    p > {
      this.text.value
    } < /p> <
    input type = "text"
    placeholder = "enter answer here" / > < /div>, div);

  }
}


shortText = (e) => {

  let div = document.createElement("div");
  document.getElementById("kiki").appendChild(div);

  ReactDOM.render( < input ref = {
      (input) => {
        this.text = input
      }
    }
    onKeyUp = {
      this.onKeyUp.bind(this, 'text')
    }
    type = "text"
    name = "text"
    placeholder = "short text field. Type question here!" / > , div);
  console.log()


}



render() {

  return ( <
    div className = "App" >
    <
    header className = "" >

    <
    /header>

    <
    div className = "row" >

    <
    div className = "col s2" >
    <
    h5 > Blocks < /h5>

    <
    ul className = "collection" >
    <
    li className = "collection-item textbox"
    onClick = {
      this.shortText.bind(this)
    } > short Text < /li>

    <
    /ul>


    <
    /div> <
    div className = "col s5"
    id = "forms" >

    <
    h5 > Form Screen < /h5>


    <
    div className = "collection"
    id = "kiki" >
    <
    form className = "col s12" >


    <
    /form> <
    /div> <
    /div> <
    div className = "col s5" >
    <
    h5 > dev preview < /h5>


    <
    div className = "collection" >
    <
    form id = "preview" >

    <
    /form>

    <
    /div> <
    /div> <
    /div>

    <
    /div>
  );
}
}

 export default App;
```

Comment: What did you do so far? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Your question is really broad. Please spend some time reviewing React's documentation and maybe try some code tutorials. Once you've done that, if you run into problems you can share a [mcve] of what you've tried with a *specific* issue that you've run into.

Comment: @ChrisR I've edited my post to include my code

Answer (score 0):

*This down below is not perfect code. I just scribbled this down;*

```js
import MyTextInput from './MyTextInput';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myElements: []
    };
  }

  addElement = (type) => {
    let addThisElement;
    switch (type) {
      case 'textinput':
        addThisElement = React.createElement(MyTextInput, { /*props here*/ };
      default:
        break;
    }

    if (addThisElement) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        arrayvar: [...prevState.myElements, addThisElement]
      }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      myElements
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <label> click to add TextInput </label>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.addElement('textinput')} >
          Add
        </button>

        <form>
          {myElements.map((el, index) => <el />)}
        </form >
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe this will point you to the right direction?

Comment: Why are you using `React.createElement` when you're already using JSX?

Comment: They do exactly the same thing, and I did it this time  on a whim kinda. Thought it would be more readable in  a switch statement

Answer (score 0):

> In the typical React dataflow, props are the only way that parent components interact with their children. To modify a child, you re-render it with new props. However, there are a few cases where you need to imperatively modify a child outside of the typical dataflow. The child to be modified could be an instance of a React component, or it could be a DOM element. For both of these cases, React provides an escape hatch. - [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

I think *React docs* should be your first place to know how to *manipulate DOM* int react.
Start Here: **[Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)**